# PHP - ¿What is the PDO equivalent to this query? real_escape_string // fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, database-connection

In advance, thanks you A LOT for your time.

**CONTEXT**

I'm new at php and my first personal task were changing SQLI connections to PDO while doing a small inventory system, all good until i saw this component who is a wonderful live search data table

**PROBLEM**

Changing it the connections i saw those:

1. $q=$conexion-> **real_escape_string** ($_POST['farmacos']);
2. $buscarFarmaco= **$conexion->query($query)** ;
3. while($filaFarmacos= **$buscarFarmaco->fetch_assoc())**;

What of course, after of an entire day of web reading + youtube i couldn't solve it.

**THIS WAS MY BEST TRY**

1. $q=$conexion-> **real_escape_string** ($_POST['farmacos']);

1.1. $q = $conexion -> prepare(); $q -> execute();

2. $buscarFarmaco= **$conexion->query($query)** ;

2.1.  $buscarFarmaco = $conexion -> prepare($query); $buscarFarmaco -> execute();

3. while($filaFarmacos= **$buscarFarmaco->fetch_assoc())**;

3.1. while($filaFarmacos = $buscarFarmaco->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)):

**SO**

Don't worry about for an exact solution, just a good advice, i will TRULY appreciate.

*There is the functional code with SQLi connections but not PDO*

```
<?php

/////// SQLI CONNECTION /////////

$host = 'localhost';
$basededatos = 'farmacia';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuario,$contraseña, $basededatos);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno)
{
    die("Fallo la conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion-> mysqli_connect_error());
}

/////// PDO CONNECTION /////////
//function conexion()
//{
//$servidor="mysql:host=localhost; dbname=farmacia";
//$usuario="root";
//$password="";

//$conexion = New PDO($servidor,$usuario,$password);
//$conexion -> SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//return $conexion;
//}

//$conexion = conexion();

//////////////// INITIAL QUERY ///////////////////////

$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM farmaco ORDER BY sto_far";

///////// OLD SQLI QUERY ////////////
if(isset($_POST['farmacos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['farmacos']); //here is the problem
    $query="SELECT * FROM farmaco WHERE 
        nom_far LIKE '%".$q."%' OR
        lab_far LIKE '%".$q."%' OR
        sto_far LIKE '%".$q."%' OR
        pre_far LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$buscarFarmaco=$conexion->query($query); //here is the other
if ($buscarFarmaco->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.= 
    '<table>
       <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <td>NOMBRE</td>
            <td>LABORATORIO</td>
            <td>STOCK</td>
            <td>PRECIO</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>';

    while($filaFarmacos= $buscarFarmaco->fetch_assoc()) //here is the final one
    {
        $tabla.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaFarmacos['nom_far'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaFarmacos['lab_far'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaFarmacos['sto_far'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaFarmacos['pre_far'].'</td>
         </tr>';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No hay stock de fármacos en este laboratorio.";
    }

echo $tabla;
?>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Thanks for the comment, dangerous detail; i'll learn more about that.